# How do I move apps to my SD card?

Tags: sd-card

Recently brought a new phone and put an SD card in it to store some of my apps but I can't move my apps from internal storage to SD? I've installed 2 apps since I got this phone so far and phone is already saying "internal storage running low"... I have already cleared data/caches from preintsalled apps...

Answer (score 0):

Some apps can't be moved to the SD card, because they wouldn't work properly anymore (widgets would suddenly dissapear, services would randomly stop).

The normal way to move apps to the sdcard is to go to settings > apps > * app you want to move* and click "Move to sdcard". If the app prevents that, the button is grayed out.

If you're running Android 6 or higher, you can format the sdcard as internal storage, then apps would be moved to the sdcard automatically. To do that, go to settings > storage > sdcard, then click on menu and select "Format as internal storage".

If you have a lower version of Android, the only solution would be rooting, which I wouldn't recommend if you don't know what you're doing. It would also allow you to move apps to the sdcard, but you can also destroy your phone completely when you're rooted and you don't know what you're doing.